# Calculate the difference of two columns and store to another column

Tags: mysql

I have table called total_table in which i have 3 columns requested_amount,total and difference.
[image: total_table]

I want the query to calculate the difference value of requested_amount and total columns (requested_amount - total) and store it in difference column of same table.

Comment: Do you want to update the records of tables?

Comment: yes @Abhishek Ginani

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is to write a simple update query like this:

```
Update total_table Set 
difference_amt = requested_amount - total
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to store the `difference_amt` field in the table...It can be fetched using query when you actually need the `difference_amt` field.So you need to change the structure of the table like this.

[image]

I've explained it in fiddle...You can check it...

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8984d7/1

Comment: you are right in a way that you don't need to store the resulting column. But there are instances when it is necessary. For example, if you're running a complex query with multiple joins, it is just easier to retrieve a calculated value rather than do it at that moment.